# How to get select value on same page without clicking submit

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="state" >
            <option value="GOA">1. GOA</option>
            <option value="Gujarat">2. Gujarat</option>
            <option value="Rajasthan">3. Rajasthan</option>
        </select> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $st = $_POST["state"];
    echo $st; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want `state` value in `$st` variable by selecting option but without click on submit button. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a Javascript function

Answer (score 2):

Just you can do with Javascript attach onchange event handler to Select tag

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="state" onchange="getValue(this)">
            <option value="GOA">1. GOA</option>
            <option value="Gujarat">2. Gujarat</option>
            <option value="Rajasthan">3. Rajasthan</option>
        </select> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<script>
function getValue(obj){
   alert(obj.value);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i need select value in php variable. can i use transfer that javascript value in php variable without change in url (?variable="value").

Comment: then send it through ajax if you don't want to reload page or submit form

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="state" class="Destination">
            <option value="GOA">1. GOA</option>
            <option value="Gujarat">2. Gujarat</option>
            <option value="Rajasthan">3. Rajasthan</option>
        </select> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <div class='ShowSelectedValueDiv'>
               //Add This Div
        </div>
    </form>
<script>
$('.Destination').change(function(){
    var Destination=$('.Destination').val();
    $.ajax({url:"ShowSelectedValue.php?Destination="+Destination,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $(".ShowSelectedValueDiv").html(result);
    }});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make One New Page,
**ShowSelectedValue.php**

```
<?
echo $a=$_GET['Destination'];
?>
```